# Comparing two consecutive lines with matching pattern and deleting the first line on match with awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file like this:

```
apple 1
apple 2
mango 3
apple 2
mango 4
mango 5
apple 3
apple 4
cherry 6
cherry 7
cherry 8
apple 5
cherry 9
```

and I want to use awk or sed in a single line to remove the line that matches the consecutive line with the pattern `apple` retaining the second line. I also want to retain rest of the lines that do not match the pattern and get the output like this:

```
apple 2
mango 3
apple 2
mango 4
mango 5
apple 4
cherry 6
cherry 7
cherry 8
apple 5
cherry 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit more optimize awk script that yours:

```
awk '$1=="apple"{l=$0;next}l{print l; l=""}1' file
```

That relies on storing into the variable `l` the line that match the `apple` pattern. The stored line is printing only when the pattern is not found.

Comment: This worked perfectly and better than my solution. Thank you.

Comment: How can this be improved if I want to eliminate every line with `apple` that has `mango` in the next line.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer after some trial and error:

```
awk '{a=$1;b=$2;row1=NR;getline;row2=NR;c=$1;d=$2;if(row1==row2 || (a=="apple" && c=="apple")) {print c " " d;} else {print a " " b;print c " " d;}}' FILE
```

This gives the output:

```
apple 2
mango 3
apple 2
mango 4
mango 5
apple 4
cherry 6
cherry 7
cherry 8
apple 5
cherry 9
```